# Drawing ellipse uses too much RAM

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, gdi+, ram

I want to draw ellipse while mouse moving.Here is my code

```
Dim released As Boolean = False
Dim firstx As Integer = 0
Dim firsty As Integer = 0

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        If released = False Then
            firstx = e.X
            firsty = e.Y
            released = True
        End If
        Dim flag As New Bitmap(PictureBox2.Image) 'This code fills RAM everytime.
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag)
        g.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.MediumOrchid, 5), firstx, firsty, e.X - firstx, e.Y - firsty)
        g.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = flag
    Else
        released = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I know defining graphics in `MouseMove` event causes that problem.It creates graphics in every single move.What is the solution ?

**Note:** `PictureBox1` and `PictureBox2` have the same picture.

Comment: If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose().  And use the *Using* statement to ensure the Graphics object is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to have the overhead of creating a bitmap to get the graphics object reference.

Instead of this:

```
Dim flag As New Bitmap(PictureBox2.Image)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag)
```

Try this

```
Dim g As Graphics = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics
```

However; what you should really be doing is handling the painting in the paint event of the picturebox you need to draw.

When the mouse moves you store the co-ordinates of the ellipse you want to draw and call `PictureBox2.Invalidate` which will in turn cause the paint event to fire.

Comment: Then how to set `PictureBox1.Image` up `g` ? `PictureBox1.Image = g` doesn't work.

Comment: `PictureBox1.Image = PictureBox2.Image`?

Comment: It uses old graphics and draws a lot of ellipses.Output is [here](http://postimg.org/image/dvgq1otxx/)

Comment: That is by design. If you want to draw fresh you need to call `g.Clear` before you draw the elipse

Comment: **Clear :** Clears the entire drawing surface and fills it with the specified background color.(from msdn)

Comment: I want to draw ellipse while mouse moving.

Comment: So you have to keep continually clearing and redrawing the elipse as the mouse moves (in the mousemove event)

Comment: How can I clear ? I tried every way but it still draws a lot of ellipses.

Comment: `PictureBox2.Invalidate` is the same as `PictureBox2.Refresh` if I use it for paint event.But my code in the question does it without refresh.I need a line of code to turn graphic old picture.I don't know graphics too much.If I use refresh event,it interrupts and ellipse is hide sometime(>100 ms).Which object should I have set up first image ?

Comment: No it isn't - Refresh is effectively synchronous whilst Invalidate is asynchronous. Calling refresh all the time will not be a good idea for performance

Comment: Tested.It works good.But still a lot of ellipse with refresh event. Please look at my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591537/drawing-event-draws-two-object).