# Drawing event draws two object

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, graphics, drawing, ram

Program has only this code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = PictureBox2.Image
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
    g.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.MediumOrchid, 5), 30, 30, 30, 30)
    g.Dispose()
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
    PictureBox2.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Before clicking `PictureBox1` is emtpty and `PictureBox2`has a white image.
[image: Before Clicking]

After clicked `PictureBox1` and `PictureBox2` both have ellipse.[image]

I think program uses one image for two `pictureBox`'es.So when I paint they are both painted.I want to set picbox2 white image and picbox1 white image with ellipse.Any solution ?

Comment: You enforce that behaviour with `PictureBox1.Image = PictureBox2.Image`.

Comment: I know that.I want to edit pic2 and save it to pic1.But pic2 mustn't change.

Comment: Then you will have to create a copy of the image.

Comment: @UweAllner then write an answer.

Comment: Picture box 2 is the same object as picture box one. Imagine you've created a balloon. Then you make a sign pointing to it called Balloon1. Then you make another sign pointing to it called Balloonl2 Then you tell someone to burst Balloon1. Then you tel the person to look at Balloon2 and they come back and say it's burst. Thats what you have. Two references to the same object. Do something to the object using the first reference, and it will be visible in the second reference. <vbg>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make a copy of the image, so you will use the same data, but not the same object, and so are safe from changes on the original object.

I am not a vb.net expert, but you may try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
    Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(PictureBox2.Image)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
    g.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Color.MediumOrchid, 5), 30, 30, 30, 30)
    g.Dispose()
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
    PictureBox2.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: It was probably down voted because "code only" answers are frowned upon.  If you want a better score you should explain what the user did wrong and why / how your code fixes the problem.

Comment: I have omitted the explanation as I had given it in the comment above. Edited it in.